# How to stop Nginx to listen to port 80?

Tags: nginx, http

I want nginx to stop listen to port 80. I only found people with bugs but no doc about doing it on purpose.
I can't disable it, and I read too :

```
#listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
```

English is not my mother tongue, but I understand "implied" meant this doesn't need to be declared, so even though it's in commentary, the server still listen to 80. How can I disable this ?
Thank you.

Comment: Where do you want nginx to listen ?

Comment: I want it to listen to 8080 or 8180

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you have commented out the listen directive nginx will fall back to it's default behaviour which is to [listen](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) on port 80 as it says in the comment after the `##`.

To have nginx listen elsewhere you need to tell it to do that using a [listen](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) directive e.g.

```
listen 8080;
```

or

```
listen 192.168.2.3:8080;
```

Comment: And it will stop listening to 80 just by declaring another port ?

Comment: Yes, that's what he is saying.

Comment: I think this will be used even for port 80 if its the 1st server. Because the 1st one if default